# How to read data from bank statement PDF in python?

Tags: python, python-pdfreader

I have to read the data from bank statement PDF which contains text and table.

I have tried some solutions provided over stack-overflow but getting errors for the most of them.

From many following one code worked for me but not getting expected results.

```
from tika import parser

rawText = parser.from_file('icici.pdf')

rawList = rawText['content'].splitlines()

print(rawList)
```

getting  output as -

```
2020-06-29 13:05:31,177 [MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Failed to see startup log message; retrying...
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Statement_MAY2020_013625568.pdf', '', '', '346001506028??PAVA0101 444501', '', '', '', '']
```

But  want  the data from the PDF file, not about PDF file.

can someone provide solution for me to read the data from bank statement PDF?

Comment: Maybe this could help you (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-contents-of-pdf-using-ocr-optical-character-recognition/)

Comment: @Toby thanks, but we don't have to use OCR, as it is less accurate, PDF is of financial records so we have focus on more accuracy. Also I tried with the OCR but facing difficulties in getting data from table structure in PDF.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_list = read_pdf(filepath,stream=True,guess=True,pages='all',
                            multiple_tables=True,
                            pandas_options={
                                'header':None})
```

try this, This code worked for me using the tabula-py module.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).